# What services allow people to send information to our organization via text message?

Tags: email, sms

I'm trying to implement a system where attendees at our events can text their email addresses to us (e.g. "text your you@domain to ###### to sign up for our list"). I've Googled around but I can't find the right search terms to find what I want. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google voice, forward all messages to gmail account, receive that gmail account in a local email program, I believe even Outlook should have enough scripting in it's rules to extract the email addresses.